# How do I use multiple spread props in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing in TypeScript. I am passing two objects as props to my React. From searching around I see I do that as such:

```
<MyComponent {...obj1} {...obj2} />
```

But how do I then use them in my actual component file?

Variations of:

```
const MyComponent = ({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }) => {
```

Don't seem to work.

Would anyone know how this is done?

Comment: you can re-write as `<MyComponent {...obj1, ...obj2} />` and then `const MyComponent = ({ name, age, ...restObj1andObj2 }) => {`

Answer (score 2):

When you spread props in creating elements you lose the handle to them. Consider the following:

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const bar = { a: 3, d: 4 };
<MyComponent {...foo} {...bar}>
```

You'll get:

```
const MyCompnent = ({ a, b, d }) => // your code
```

So you'll have no reference to `foo` and `bar`, because you've spread both and the `a` prop may belong to either one depending on the spread order.
You can send foo and bar as individual props if you want access to them in component.

```
<MyComponent foo={foo} bar={bar}>
```